javafx.concurrent.Task: How to separate library and GUI?
I have a JavaFX application where one functionality involves searching (large) binary data for specific patterns. To keep the GUI responsive, I am creating a concurrent task and put it on a differen thread:
public void search(SearchPattern pattern) {
    
    Task<ObservableList<...>> task = new Task<>() {
        @Override protected ObservableList<...> call() throws Exception {

            try {                    
                for(int i=0;i<....size();i++) {
                    if (isCancelled()) {
                        break;
                    }
                    if(i%50000 == 0) {
                        updateProgress(i, entries.size());
                    }
                    if(pattern.matches(entries.get(i))) {
                        // do stuff
                    }                        
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                // IO cleanup
            }
            return FXCollections.observableArrayList(...);
        }
    };

    progressBar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());

    task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
        unregisterRunningTask(task);
        searchResults = task.getValue();
    });

    Thread thread = new Thread(task);
    registerRunningTask(task);
    thread.setDaemon(false);
    thread.start();
}

This works fine, however mingles (library) functionality with GUI code. In particular I would like to put the search code into a separate library, write test-cases for that functionality - completely automated, without a GUI - and of course when testing from the commandline, a separate thread is not needed. Right now, I am limited to putting pattern.matches(entries.get(i)) in that library. A cleaner way would be to have a function
searchpattern(filename) {
    for(int=0;i< ... ;i++) {
       ...
    }
    return observableArrayList(...);
}

in the library that includes the complete loop, write my test-cases and benchmarks on that, and then somehow involve that function in the GUI code. The problem I face when separating this code is:
updateProgress() requires a reference to a task. Of course I could always create a task when trying to implement test-cases, i.e. even when invoking searchpattern(filename) from a non-GUI context. I could simply omit any progress updates in my code, but that creates a very bad user-experience.
Is there any other way to pass updates from that (potentially) long-running function using some abstraction layer, that makes this function easy in a library both from a (threaded) GUI context and a non-threaded commandline context?

Create a class in your library module that performs the actual work. Design the class so that it isn't aware JavaFX even exists. If you want the class to be able to report progress then design it to accept one or more types of "listeners". A listener can be your own custom type or you can use a predefined type from somewhere (e.g., a type from java.util.function, if it makes sense). Then you can use this class in both your CLI app and your GUI app. For the GUI, the Task would either accept an instance of your class or create one itself, add a listener, and then start the work.

If you don't want the library class to support a listener mechanism, then you could also poll it from the UI (the library class would just need an appropriate getProgress()-like method). Your task could, for example, start an AnimationTimer that polled the library class and updated the task's progress on each rendering frame, stopping the timer when the task stops. @Slaw's comment above is probably a simpler and cleaner approach, but this could be used if you really don't want to implement listener notifications or if you are using a third-party library that doesn't have them.

For general background info (not a specific solution in your case), see the info and links in JavaFX complex project architecture

Here are two approaches. To make things more concrete, suppose we have a class that implements a potentially long-running process on a list:
public abstract class ListProcessor<T> {

    private final List<T> items ;

    public ListProcessor(List<T> items) {
        this.items = items ;
    }

    public void process() {
        for (int i = 0 ; i < items.size(); i++) {
            processItem(items.get(i));
        }
    }

    public abstract processItem(T item);
}

(I'm making a ton of assumptions here about the list not being modified during processing, etc.)
The first approach is as described by @Slaw in a comment. In this approach, your external library class keeps a list of listeners that are notified when the number of items processed changes. You could simply use a DoubleConsumer for this. For example:
public abstract class ListProcessor<T> {

    private final List<T> items ;

    private final List<DoubleConsumer> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public ListProcessor(List<T> items) {
        this.items = items ;
    }

    public void addListener(DoubleConsumer listener) {
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeListener(DoubleConsumer listener) {
        listeners.remove(listener);
    }

    public void process() {
        int n = items.size();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) {
            processItem(items.get(i));
            listeners.forEach(l -> l.accept(1.0 * i / n));
        }
    }

    public abstract processItem(T item);
}

You can use this in a task as follows:
List<Widget> widgets = ... ;
ListProcessor<Widget> widgetProcessor = new WidgetProcessor(widgets);

Task<Void> widgetTask = new Task<>() {
    @Override
    protected Void call() {
        DoubleConsumer progressUpdater = prog -> updateProgress(prog, 1.0);
        widgetProcessor.addListener(progressUpdater);
        widgetProcessor.process();
        widgetProcessor.removeListener(progressUpdater);
        updateProgress(1.0, 1.0);
        return null;
    }
};

progressBar.progressProperty().bind(widgetTask.progressProperty());
// ...
executor.execute(widgetTask);

This relies on your library class implementing a listener-notification mechanism. If you don't want to do that, or if you are using some third-party library that doesn't implement it, you can poll the processing object for its current progress. I would do the polling from an AnimationTimer, though other approaches are possible. The minimum requirement (as far as I can tell) is that the processing object has a way of reporting its progress in a thread-safe manner (as you will be polling it from a different thread to the one that is updating it).
So, for example:
public abstract class ListProcessor<T> {

    private final List<T> items ;

    private volatile double progress = 0.0;

    public ListProcessor(List<T> items) {
        this.items = items ;
    }

    public void process() {
        int n = items.size();
        for (int i = 0 ; i < n; i++) {
            processItem(items.get(i));
            progress = (1.0 * i / n);
        }
    }

    public double getProgress() {
        return progress;
    }

    public abstract processItem(T item);
}

And then
List<Widget> widgets = ... ;
ListProcessor<Widget> widgetProcessor = new WidgetProcessor(widgets);

Task<Void> widgetTask = new Task<>() {
    @Override
    protected Void call() {
        AnimationTimer progressUpdater = new AnimationTimer() {
            @Override
            public void handle(long now) {
                updateProgress(widgetProcessor.getProgress(), 1.0);
            }
        };
        progressUpdater.start();
        widgetProcessor.process();
        progressUpdater.stop();
        updateProgress(1.0, 1.0);
        return null;
    }
};

progressBar.progressProperty().bind(widgetTask.progressProperty());
// ...
executor.execute(widgetTask);

In both cases, you should make sure you implement proper clean-up in the case of exceptions being thrown, etc. (It's probably better to do the clean-up in a state listener or in the succeeded() and failed() methods.)

The listener stuff and polling is overkill, IMHO.  You can update progress from inside the Task, so just pass a Consumer to the routine that does the work from the Task.  Something as simple as {progress -> updateProgress(progress)} would do the trick.  No need to worry about the FXAT as updateProgress() can be run from any thread.  See my article:  https://www.pragmaticcoding.ca/javafx/elements/task-progress

@DaveB The listener approach is almost identical to what you're suggesting, unless I'm missing something. It just supports an arbitrary number of updaters.

No, I'm suggesting that the Task supplies a Callback to the routine that does the work, and that Callback calls Task.updateProgress(). No listeners.  Maybe I should post an answer with this approach?

@DaveB The listener is a callback, no? They are essentially synonyms. To provide it you'd need a setProgressCallback(...) method and a field, which is almost no less code than a list of listeners and an add method...

The original question just asked to pull the "search code" out of the Task, and into some place where it can be tested outside of the Task environment.  No need for an entire class and associated Listener structure.  In MVC just a method in the Model would do the trick.  A simple Callback passed as a method parameter allows all of the OP's requirements without any fuss.  Is a Listener just a Callback?  Sure, but it's another unneeded layer of complexity, so why bother.

@DaveB Probably you should post an answer. You say "no need for an entire class" but the OP says "I would like to put the search code into a separate library", which I interpret to mean (at a minimum) a separate class. But perhaps I am not understanding your intent.

It's done, take a look.

The fundamental issue is that Task.updateProgress() is protected, and cannot be called from outside the Task.  This means that moving the search code out to an external library will mean that it won't be able to directly call Task.updateProgress().  James_D has described a way to do this by creating a class which implements Listeners, but this can be done - perhaps more simply - by supplying a Callback parameter to the search method:
public void search(SearchPattern pattern) {
    
    Task<ObservableList<...>> task = new Task<>() {
        @Override protected ObservableList<...> call() throws Exception {
            return someLibraryClass.searchRoutine((idx, totalWork) -> updateProgress(idx, totalWork);
        }
    };

    progressBar.progressProperty().bind(task.progressProperty());

    task.setOnSucceeded(e -> {
        unregisterRunningTask(task);
        searchResults = FXCollections.observableArrayList(task.getValue());
    });

    Thread thread = new Thread(task);
    registerRunningTask(task);
    thread.setDaemon(false);
    thread.start();
}

And the search routine can simply be a method in some other class:
class SomeLibraryClass() {

   .
   .
   .
   public List<...> searchRoutine(BiConsumer<Integer, Integer> callBack) {
      try {                    
          for(int i=0;i<....size();i++) {
              if (isCancelled()) {
                  break;
              }
              if(i%50000 == 0) {
                  callBack.accept(i, entries.size());
              }
              if(pattern.matches(entries.get(i))) {
                  // do stuff
              }                        
          }
      } catch (IOException e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
      } finally {
          // IO cleanup
      }
      return whatEverListWasCreated;
  }
  .
  .
  .
}

Now SomeLibraryClass.searchRoutine() can be called from any place, and if there is no need to monitor progress, just pass it something like (x,y) -> {} and it will work just fine.  So it can be tested without issue.
This code is still very recognizable as the code in the OP, just with the search functionality extracted to its own method.  The only other change was to have the Task simple return a List or some other kind of non-JavaFX Collection, and then wrap it into an ObservableList in the onSucceeded() method.  This keeps all of the JavaFX related code on the FXAT.
